# How to declare a data member reference in tclOO

Tags: oop, tcl

I am trying to hold a reference to a variable as a data member in `tclOO`. Is there any construct that can simulate the `upvar` command that is  used inside functions.

```
oo::class create TestClass {
variable refToVar
constructor {varRef} {
    set varRef [string range $varRef 1 [expr [string length $varRef] -1]]
    # upvar $varRef temp
    # set refToVar $temp
    upvar $varRef refToVar
}

method getRefToVar {} {
    return $refToVar
}

method setRefToVar {value} {
    set refToVar $value
}

}

proc testProc {varRef} {
set varRef [string range $varRef 1 [expr [string length $varRef] -1]]
upvar $varRef temp
set temp 5
}

puts "start"
set x 100
puts $x

puts "proc test"
testProc {$x}
puts $x

puts "tclOO test"
TestClass create tst {$x}
puts [tst getRefToVar]
tst setRefToVar 20
puts [tst getRefToVar]
puts $x
```

Basically i want to achieve the same behaviour with the  `oo::class` that I am doing with the `proc`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Donal has answered your question, but there is a better way to do it.

```
oo::class create TestClass {
    variable varRef
    constructor args {
        lassign $args varRef
    }

    method getRefToVar {} {
        upvar 0 $varRef refToVar
        return $refToVar
    }

    method setRefToVar {value} {
        upvar 0 $varRef refToVar
        set refToVar $value
    }
}
```

Here, you supply the `TestClass` object with the qualified name of the variable, like `::x` for the global variable `x`, or `::foobar::x` for the `x` variable in the `foobar` namespace. You save this name in the instance variable `varRef`.

When you want to read from or write to this variable, you first create a local reference to it:

```
upvar 0 $varRef refToVar
```

This means that in the method where you are invoking this command, `refToVar` is a reference or alias to the variable whose name is stored in `varRef`.

You can do the same thing in a command procedure:

```
proc testProc {varRef} {
    upvar 0 $varRef refToVar
    set refToVar 5
}
```

Testing it:

```
puts "start"
set x 100
puts $x

puts "proc test"
testProc ::x
puts $x

puts "tclOO test"
TestClass create tst ::x
puts [tst getRefToVar]
tst setRefToVar 20
puts [tst getRefToVar]
puts $x
```

Note how the names are written differently.

If you somehow don't know the qualified name of the variable, this should be helpful:

```
TestClass create tst [namespace which -variable x]
```

BTW: you don't have to write

```
string range $varRef 1 [expr [string length $varRef] -1]
```

there is an abbreviated form for that:

```
string range $varRef 1 end
```

but you don't have to write that either: to remove zero or more dollar signs from the left end of a string, just

```
string trimleft $varRef \$
```

but you don't have to write that either: you don't need to add the dollar sign when passing a variable name:

```
proc bump varName {
    upvar 1 $varName var
    incr var
}
set x 10
# => 10
bump x
set x
# => 11
```

Documentation: [expr](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/expr.htm), [incr](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/incr.htm), [lassign](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lassign.htm), [namespace](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/namespace.htm), [proc](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/proc.htm), [puts](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/puts.htm), [set](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/set.htm), [string](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/string.htm), [upvar](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/upvar.htm)

Answer (score 1):

The equivalent is `upvar`. *However* you need to run the `upvar` in the right context, that of the object's state namespace and not the method (because you want `refToVar` to be by the overall object) because `upvar` always makes its references from in the current stack context, which means local variables in *both* cases by default.

TclOO provides the tools though.

```
my eval [list upvar 2 $varref refToVar]
```

It's a `2` because there's one level for `my eval` and another level for the method. ***MAKE SURE*** *that you only refer to variables in a namespace* (global variables are in the global namespace) *this way or you'll have pain.* It's probably not a good idea to keep references to variables around inside an object as they can be run from all sorts of contexts, but it should work.

You can also use the `namespace upvar` command inside that generated `my eval` to do the same sorts of thing, since anything you can write that is sensible can be described using namespace/varname coordinates instead of stack-index/varname coordinates.

---

[EDIT]: In fact, Tcl takes care to avoid the evil case, and throws an error if you try. Here's a boiled-down version of the class:

```
oo::class create Foo {
    constructor v {
        # This is done like this because this sort of operation is not affected
        # by the 'variable' declaration; it's a bit unusual...
        my eval [list upvar 2 $v ref]
    }
    variable ref
    method bar {} {
        # Just some normal usage
        puts $ref
    }
}
```

Let's show this working normally:

```
% set x 123
123
% set y [Foo new x]
::oo::Obj12
% $y bar
123
% incr x
124
% $y bar
124
```

OK, that all looks good. Now, let's go for attaching it to a local variable:

```
proc abc {} {
    set x 234
    set y [Foo new x]
    # Try the call
    $y bar
    incr x
    $y bar
    # Try returning it to see what happens with the lifespan
    return $y
}
```

But calling it doesn't work out:

```
% abc
bad variable name "ref": can't create namespace variable that refers to procedure variable
% puts $errorInfo
bad variable name "ref": can't create namespace variable that refers to procedure variable
    while executing
"upvar 2 x ref"
    (in "my eval" script line 1)
    invoked from within
"my eval [list upvar 2 $v ref]"
    (class "::Foo" constructor line 1)
    invoked from within
"Foo new x"
    (procedure "abc" line 3)
    invoked from within
"abc"
```

So there you go; you can link an external global (or namespace) variable easily enough into an object, but it had better not be a local variable. It *might* be possible to do extra work to make using a local variable that is actually an `upvar` to a global variable work, but why would you bother?

Comment: I am new to tcl, why should i only refer to variables in a namespace

Comment: @alex529 Lifespan management mainly. Objects aren't bound to the stack, as they are both command-like things and namespace-like things, so having an object that has a permanent link to a variable whose real existence is in a stack frame (i.e., it's a local variable somewhere) is a Bad Idea. And in fact, if you try you get an error: `bad variable name "refToVar": can't create namespace variable that refers to procedure variable`. The first part seems to be misleading but the second is accurate; I guess it's not been thought about before because people don't try very often as it is silly. :-)